# Inequality between factorial and exponential

Tags: inequality, exponential-function, factorial

Trying to find a nice way to simplify the question:

Which is bigger 2000! or 1000^2000?

I don't know what kind of reasoning I can apply here.

Comment: Hint: compare 999*1001 to 1000^2

Comment: Ah, that does it. I was trying to regroup in different ways but that definitely works, thanks.

Comment: Don't forget about 2000 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [Factorial Inequality problem $\left(\frac n2\right)^n > n! > \left(\frac n3\right)^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144176/factorial-inequality-problem) it is shown that

$$n!<\left(\frac n2\right)^n.$$ For $n=2000$ we have

$$2000!<\left(\frac {2000}{2}\right)^{2000}=1000^{2000}.$$