# Find limit of $\lim\limits_{x \to\infty}{\left({{(x!)^2}\over{(2x)!}}\right)}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm practising solving some limits and, currently, I'm trying to solve $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}{\left({{(x!)^2}\over{(2x)!}}\right)}$.

**What I have done:**

- I have attempted to simplify the fraction until I've reached an easier one to solve, however, I'm currently stuck at the following:

$$
\lim_{x→\infty}{\left({{(x!)^2}\over{(2x)!}}\right)}=
\lim_{x→\infty}{\left({{(\prod_{i=1}^{x}i)^2}\over{\prod_{i=1}^{2x}i}}\right)}=
\lim_{x→\infty}{\left({
   {
      {\prod_{i=1}^{x}i}\cdot{\prod_{i=1}^{x}i}
   }\over{
   {
      {\prod_{i=1}^{x}}i}\cdot{\prod_{i=x+1}^{2x}i}
   }
}\right)}=
\lim_{x→\infty}{\left({
   {\prod_{i=1}^{x}i}\over{
   {\prod_{i=x+1}^{2x}i}}
}\right)}.
$$

- Instinctively, I can see that the limit is equal to $0$, since the numerator is always less than the denominator, thus approaching infinity slower as $x→\infty$.

**Question:**

- How can I continue solving the above limit w/o resorting to instinct to determine it equals $0$ ?
- If the above solution can't go any further, is there a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: You use the variable $x$ for integers, is that correct? (If so, that's slightly non-standard -- people usually go for $n$, $k$, or $m$ for integer variables)

Comment: @ClementC. I think that's not a problem at all.

Comment: Also, two questions: (i) are you familiar with/allowed to use Stirling's approximation? (ii) if not, are you familiar with properties of the Binomial distribution?

Comment: @Botond It is not a problem, and I never wrote it was. It'd be equally correct to write $\clubsuit$ for the variable, for that matter. But it is somewhat off-putting at first glance, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing from what you have mentioned,
$$0 \le \lim_{x\to\infty}{\left({
   {\prod_{i=1}^{x}i}\over{
   {\prod_{i=x+1}^{2x}i}}
}\right)} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\prod_{i=1}^{x}\frac{i}{i+x} \le \lim_{x\to\infty}\prod_{i=1}^{x}\frac{x}{x+x} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{2^x}=0.$$

Answer (score 4):

Let $a_n={{(n!)^2}\over{(2n)!}}$ and note that by [ratio test](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-ratio-test-for-sequence-convergence)

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}={{((n+1)!)^2}\over{(2n+2)!}}{{(2n)!}\over{(n!)^2}}=\frac{(n+1)^2}{(2n+2)(2n+1)}\to \frac14$$

then $$a_n\to 0$$

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Are you sure? It was proved to me during my course in calculus and analysis also for sequence, see the link.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus if the corresponding series converges (which is here proved by the ratio test) then its limit is $0$ as $n$ approaches infinity. +1 from me!

Comment: @user372003 it is also a well known result for sequecences, as root test and ratio-root criteria, Thanks

Comment: I believe you should interchange numerator and denominator in the definition of $a_n$.

Comment: ops...thanks just a typo of course!

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* ${n\choose k}={n-1\choose k-1}+{n-1\choose k}$

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Stirling's Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) and use asymptotics.

Comment: ah, darn, changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Define $a_n=\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}$. Then it is easy to show that $a_{n+1}<a_n$ and $a_n\in (0,1)$. So $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ exists. Then notice that 
$$a_{n+1}=a_n\cdot \frac{n}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}.$$
Take limit $n\to\infty$ on both sides, we get $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Use stirling's approximation, namely that
$$
n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n.
$$
Hence
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2\pi n\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{2n}.}
{\sqrt{4\pi n}\times2^{2n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{2n}}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{\pi n}}{2^{2n}}=0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Stirling formula may be difficult to remember, but the simpler one below is extremely useful and allows you to solve most asymptotic results with factorials:

[Factorial Inequality problem $\left(\frac n2\right)^n > n! > \left(\frac n3\right)^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144176/factorial-inequality-problem-left-frac-n2-rightn-n-left-frac-n3-righ?noredirect=1&lq=1)

You get $\quad\dfrac{n^{2n}}{9^n}< (n!)^2 < \dfrac{n^{2n}}{4^n}$

And also $\quad\dfrac{4^nn^{2n}}{9^n}< (2n)! < \dfrac{4^nn^{2n}}{4^n}$

So by dividing positive quantities $0<\dfrac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}<\dfrac{n^{2n}9^n}{4^n4^nn^{2n}}=\left(\dfrac 9{16}\right)^n\to 0$

---

You can also notice that in this case $\dfrac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}=C_{2n}^n\ge C_{2n}^1\ge 2n\to\infty$ so its inverse is going to zero.