# Prove $\sqrt{n!} \gt \frac{n}{2}$ $\forall$ $n \ge 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, induction, factorial

Prove that $$\sqrt{n!} \gt \frac{n}{2}$$ $\forall$ $n \ge 1$

My try:

I Tried using Induction:

$P(1)$ is True obviously.

Let $P(k)$ Be True Then we have

$$\sqrt{k!} \gt \frac{k}{2}$$

Now $$\sqrt{(k+1)!}=\sqrt{k+1}\sqrt{k!}\gt \sqrt{k+1}\frac{k}{2}$$

Now Since $x^2-x-1 \gt 0$ $\forall $ $x \ge 2$ We have

$$k^2 \gt k+1$$ $\forall$ $k \ge 2$

Hence

$$k \gt \sqrt{k+1}$$

Hence

$$\sqrt{(k+1)!} \gt \sqrt{k+1}\frac{k}{2}\gt \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{k+1}\sqrt{k+1}=\frac{k+1}{2}$$

Hence Proved

Is there any alternate approach?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144176/factorial-inequality-problem-left-frac-n2-rightn-n-left-frac-n3-righ) and the linked questions for similar questions (not exact duplicates).

Answer (score 5):

Assume $n \geq 2$,
Then, $$\frac{4}{3} < n$$
$$\Leftrightarrow n < 4(n-1)$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \frac{n}{4} < (n-1).$$
Then 
$$\frac{n}{4} < (n-1) \leq (n-1)!$$
Multiply by $n$ and take the square root
$$ \frac{n}{2} < \sqrt{n!}$$

Answer (score 1):

For all $n>1$ it is enough to prove that $n(n-1) > n^2/4$.
Iff $3 n^2/4 > n$. For $n=2$ it is true. $n^2$ grows faster than $n$ so it is also true for larger $n$.

For $n=1$ we can see it is true by substitution.