# Proof by induction using definition of e

Tags: induction

I'm working with this example that I'm trying to prove using induction:

[image]

I have two inequalities, so I have to do 2 induction proofs for each inequality seperately.

Treating the left inequality, after the base case and the induction assumption, I reach this point:

$(m+1)! > (m+1)(\frac{m}{3})^m$

Now, the question arises, is $(m+1)(\frac{m}{3})^m>(\frac{m+1}{3})^{m+1}$

I think that you can then see, after some simplications, that we get:

$3 > (1+1/m)^m$

Which then can be proved using the definition of e, I assume? Either way, I'd like to hear about your opinions, is this a good way of solving the problem using induction?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Factorial Inequality problem $\left(\frac n2\right)^n &gt; n! &gt; \left(\frac n3\right)^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144176/factorial-inequality-problem-left-frac-n2-rightn-n-left-frac-n3-righ)

Comment: If you also show that $(1+\frac{1}{m})^m$ is strictly increasing , then this approach is fine.

Comment: $(1+1/m)^m < 3$ ⇔ $1+t < 3^t$, which is much easier to prove.

Comment: @Peter How would one show that it's strictly increasing, without using derivatives? Could I just compare the ratio of the (m+1):th term and m:th term?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you :)

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos:  Here OP asks for proof using induction, whereas the question you linked asks for proof *not* using induction

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Right. I've rectracted my vote.